# Thermal bluetooth printer stops printing halfway in ionic bluetooth serial for PT-380 model

Tags: ionic-framework, printing, bluetooth, thermal-printer

My PT-380 model printer stops printing half way through the print. I am using bluetooth serial ionic plugin. It works fine in other devices but not working only for this model. Is this a plugin issue or printer issue or the plugin is not supporting the device?

```
testPrint(address)
  {
    let printData="Lists are made up of multiple rows of items which can contain text, buttons, toggles, icons, thumbnails, and much more. Lists generally contain items with similar data content, such as images and text.Lists support several interactions including swiping items to reveal options, dragging to reorder items within the list, and deleting items. 444444444444444444444444444444444 33333333333333333333333333333333333 222222222222222222222222222222222 111111111111111111111111111111111 0000000000000000000000000000000000 7777777777777777777777777777777 8888888888888888888888888888888 999999999999999999999999999999 666666666666666666666666666666666666666 55555555555555555555555555555555555555 Flutter includes a ListView widget for working with Lists, which is the fundamental concept of displaying data in the mobile apps. The ListView is a perfect standard for displaying lists that contains only a few items. ListView also includes ListTitle widget, which gives more properties for the visual structure to a list of data.444444444444444444444444444444444 33333333333333333333333333333333333 222222222222222222222222222222222 111111111111111111111111111111111 0000000000000000000000000000000000 7777777777777777777777777777777 8888888888888888888888888888888 999999999999999999999999999999 666666666666666666666666666666666666666 55555555555555555555555555555555555555 consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborumLorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum\n\n\n\n"
      printData += "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborumLorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborumLorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborumLorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborumLorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum\n\n";
    let xyz=this.connectBT(address).subscribe(data=>{
      this.btSerial.write(printData).then(dataz=>{
        console.log("WRITE SUCCESS",dataz);

        let mno=this.alertCtrl.create({
          title:"Print SUCCESS!",
          buttons:['Dismiss']
        });
        mno.present();

        xyz.unsubscribe();
      },errx=>{
        console.log("WRITE FAILED",errx);
        let mno=this.alertCtrl.create({
          title:"ERROR "+errx,
          buttons:['Dismiss']
        });
        mno.present();
      });
      },err=>{
        console.log("CONNECTION ERROR",err);
        let mno=this.alertCtrl.create({
          title:"ERROR "+err,
          buttons:['Dismiss']
        });
        mno.present();
      });

  }
```